# Mint - Can't login "your home directory..." error

Tags: linux-mint, login, home

I've recently installed Mint Linux, and when I try to login in the GUI it gives the following error message

> your home directory is listed as /home/username but does not appear to
>   exist

Then when I click OK appears this message

> User's $HOME/.dmrc file is being ignored

And then it tells me that it cannot make login and forces me to log off.

What do I do?

Comment: @PedroMendes gave an incomplete answer. When a new user is added, his home directory is endowed with a small number of files and directories, some of them hidden. They can be found in `/etc/skel`, and be copied over to the new home directory. Pedro's answer missed this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, let's create the username home folder then. To do that just follow this steps:

1 - On the login menu press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to open the terminal
2 - Log in with your user
3 - Execute the commands

```
sudo mkdir /home/username
sudo chown username /home/username
```

4 - Then press Ctrl + Alt + F8 to return to the GUI

Hopefully now you can login :)

**Edit**

Thanks to @MariusMatutiae for this aditional step

> When a new user is added, his home directory is endowed with a small
>   number of files and directories, some of them hidden. They can be
>   found in /etc/skel, and be copied over to the new home directory.

After you login for the first time, open a terminal window and type the following command:

```
cp -a /etc/skel/. /home/username
```

This will copy all the files inside skel to the username folder.

Comment: Wouldn't you need root permissions to add to `/home`? Also, you'd probably want to change the group ownership for this new directory, i.e. `sudo chown username: /home/username`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your home directory listed in '/' using root-shell in recovery mode, then this might help.

Boot into linux mint recovery mode, then go to root-shell prompt. As it loads the file system in read only mode, you need to remount it with read/write permission, use the following command.

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

after it remounts try these commands and login using your username.

```
chown root:root /home
chown -R username:username /home/username
```

(replace 'username' with your own details of course.)